# Fancybox won't turn right on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I implemented the fancy box as usual:

```
<a href="img/fotos/architektur/1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1"><img src="img/fotos/architektur/thumbs/1.jpg"></a>
<a href="img/fotos/architektur/2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1"><img src="img/fotos/architektur/thumbs/2.jpg"></a>
```

It works totally cool on Desktops but on my iPad it only works with the left control. A move forward to the next image (right arrow) doesn't work... Why?

Answer (score 0):

if "cyclic" is set to true, maybe there's an overlay issue

did you try to display the page in a desktop window resized to ipad resolution? maybe with "Pesticide" activated ? (it's extension for chrome, will make outlines on all elements)

```
.fancybox-overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
/*    z-index: 9999;*/
background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}
```

Comment: Cyclic isn't set... This is my config 

   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    maxWidth : 800,
    maxHeight : 600,
    openEffect : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
   });

Desktop window scaled to iPad still works... :(

Comment: are you able to loop through images with clicking on previous? this still seems to me that it's overlay problem, like invisible box on top of fancybox

Comment: Yes, I am able to loop them previous. I don't see a overlay over the fancybox-next button... But when clicking on the ipad, the next-button appears and when I click it shortly disappears and appears again...

Comment: try the css that I've added

Comment: Doesn't make any change :(

Comment: any update on issue ? I search for this problem and found many similar problems with buttons on ipad. https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/423